# Grub won't boot windows after update from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: grub2, windows, dual-boot, updates

thanks for your time and reading this, here's the deal:

i upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 and everything worked out until i rebooted, i had 11.10 sucessfully running as a dual boot with windows vista.
when i rebooted, my GRUB was shot to hell, what ever option i selected it said partion not found or something similar... booting into a live version on a thumb drive and running bootrepair from there fixed the issue... but only for ubuntu, when i try to boot into windows it only goes back to GRUB.
i'm not at home, and heres a list of what i have here with me...

- 1 4gb thumb drive, empty
- 1 8gb thumb drive, windows vista installer bootable
- 1 old laptop, the one i try to save, optical drive is not existent
- 2 Mbps internet connection

can you help me get back into my windows without having to reinstall windows?
or at least show me a way how to use my illustrator through a virtual machine or something?

here's my grub cfg

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod vbe
  insmod vga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}

insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos2)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1063e402-b14f-45e5-92b6-d20a2e3a717e
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root='(hd0,msdos2)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1063e402-b14f-45e5-92b6-d20a2e3a717e
  set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
  set lang=de_DE
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "${linux_gfx_mode}" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 3.2.0-24-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1063e402-b14f-45e5-92b6-d20a2e3a717e
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic root=UUID=1063e402-b14f-45e5-92b6-d20a2e3a717e ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 3.2.0-24-generic (Wiederherstellungsmodus)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1063e402-b14f-45e5-92b6-d20a2e3a717e
    echo    'Linux 3.2.0-24-generic wird geladen …'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic root=UUID=1063e402-b14f-45e5-92b6-d20a2e3a717e ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Initiale Ramdisk wird geladen …'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic
}
submenu "Previous Linux versions" {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 3.0.0-19-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1063e402-b14f-45e5-92b6-d20a2e3a717e
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-19-generic root=UUID=1063e402-b14f-45e5-92b6-d20a2e3a717e ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-19-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 3.0.0-19-generic (Wiederherstellungsmodus)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1063e402-b14f-45e5-92b6-d20a2e3a717e
    echo    'Linux 3.0.0-19-generic wird geladen …'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-19-generic root=UUID=1063e402-b14f-45e5-92b6-d20a2e3a717e ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Initiale Ramdisk wird geladen …'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-19-generic
}
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1063e402-b14f-45e5-92b6-d20a2e3a717e
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos2)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1063e402-b14f-45e5-92b6-d20a2e3a717e
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry "Windows Vista (loader) (on /dev/sda1)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2C9E66B39E6674EC
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid` from a live session.

Comment: i'm running my ubuntu 12.04 tight now, will this do?

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun  6 17:10 0f16b1e6-269a-4407-a69c-6fdb8b713fe5 -> ../../sda3

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun  6 17:10 1063e402-b14f-45e5-92b6-d20a2e3a717e -> ../../sda2

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun  6 17:10 12A6C30B2C843382 -> ../../sda4

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun  6 22:20 1306-192E -> ../../sdd1

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun  6 17:10 2C9E66B39E6674EC -> ../../sda1

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun  6 17:33 9291-85B2 -> ../../sdb1

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun  6 17:33 E0FD-1813 -> ../../sdc1

Comment: Please run boot info script http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/ and post the RESULTS.txt which it produces.

Comment: Hi Jordan, since the file is to long to post it, i've uploaded it, you can find it here:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1731341/RESULTS.txt

thank you for your help

Comment: do me a favor and run `sudo fdisk -l` and include the information, i want to see if your partitions have been getting overwritten

Answer (score 1):

According to your Boot Info Script output you have accidentally installed grub's boot sector to your Windows partition (grub's boot sector should always be installed to the MBR, never to a partition). If you never ran grub-install yourself then maybe Boot Repair did this, in which case you should file a bug report against Boot Repar. To fix this problem you'll need to restore the Windows PBR. You can do that by following this guide: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/bootinfoscript/index.php?title=Boot_Problems:Boot_Sector .

Comment: This is the correct answer as NTFS partition boot sectors have to have a Windows (not grub) boot signature.

Comment: This answer could be better if it explained how you figured out which partition GRUB is installed on and how you figured out which partition Windows is installed on.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing UEFI loader to the other one available.  This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. `sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg` to open the file as super-user so you can write to it
2. go to the section

   ```
   ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
   menuentry "Windows Vista (loader) (on /dev/sda1)" --class windows --class os {
   insmod part_msdos
   insmod ntfs
   set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2C9E66B39E6674EC
   chainloader +1
   }
   ### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
   ```
3. just before the line `chainloader +1` add the following line:

   ```
   drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
   ```

   then the section should look like

   ```
   ### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
   menuentry "Windows Vista (loader) (on /dev/sda1)" --class windows --class os {
   insmod part_msdos
   insmod ntfs
   set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
   search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2C9E66B39E6674EC
   drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
   chainloader +1
   }
   ### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
   ```
4. save the file and exit.
5. reboot the system and boot to Windows Vista.

Comment: hi, thanks, tried it but didn't work, when i select vista ist only lets the screen go blank for half a second and then it's back to grub :-( do i have to update grub or anything to make the changes work?

my section with the changes...

class os {
 insmod part_msdos
 insmod ntfs
 set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2C9E66B39E6674EC
 drivemap -s (hd0) ${root} 
 chainloader +1
}

Comment: change the line `set root='(hd0,msdos1)'` to `set root=(hd0,1)` and check if that works, and also check the if file `30_os-prober` exists under `/etc/grub.d/` or not.

Comment: allright, back again, first of all thank you for the time you're investing in my problem.

30_os-prober esists und /grub.d/ 

i edited the line as you told me to...

but the problem remains the same :-(


here's the updated section:

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry "Windows Vista (loader) (on /dev/sda1)" --class windows --class os {
 insmod part_msdos
 insmod ntfs
 set root='(hd0,1)'
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2C9E66B39E6674EC
 drivemap -s (hd0) ${root} 
 chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

Comment: Ok, I think the Windows bootloader might have been corrupted or pointing to some invalid partition. [See this post for a reference](http://askubuntu.com/a/144512/27559) and go to the **second part** under the section **Original post**. Follow those steps(1 through 5), and see if that works. Note, you will be needing your Windows Vista Installer with startup repair option.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jordan, you need to fix the bootsector of sda1.

For information Boot-Repair installs GRUB in the MBR(s) by default, and it doesn't have any option to install GRUB in the PBR of a Windows partition, so this can't be a bug of B-R.